# How to concatenate multiple results using cell references

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that web scrapes literature data and returns the results. The problem with my current code (refer to image) is that it lists all the results in a single column (image ref). I would like to use the last cell of each result (SO then blank cell below) as a reference point to concatenate all the corresponding author results in to one single cell. I am not sure what syntax to use to be able to do this but any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  Sub ReturnFAUResults()

        Dim r As Range

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' reference results sheet
        If IsEmpty(.Range("A1")) Then .Range("A1").Value = "dummy header" ' 
        if A1 is empty, put a "dummy" header to make AutoFilter work properly

           .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Offset(, -1) ' 
        reference referenced sheet column A range from row 1 down to column B 
        last 
             not empty cell
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=R[-1]C" ' fill 
             referenced range blank cells with the same value as the not 
             empty cell above
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=FAU"
             On Error Resume Next
             Set r = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 
             1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
             On Error GoTo 0
             If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Copy Worksheets("Search 
             Results").Range("A7")
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).ClearContents ' clear cell with 
             formulas
             If .Range("A1").Value = "dummy header" Then 
            .Range("A1").ClearContents ' remove any "dummy" header
             End With
             End With

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**returned results**
[image: returned results]

**beginning raw results**
[image: beginning raw results]

**end of each raw result**
[image: end of each raw result]