# How can I combine the multiple strings in to one cell by using a reference cell in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro code that returns search results given a search criteria by using the AutoFilter syntax.

The purpose of this code is to search literature results and return all the results directly to Excel.

The problem I am running in to is that the current code is simply listing all the authors in the entire search results sheet and listing them in column A, one author at a time.

For each title there are multiple authors, so I would like to use a function to combine all author results for a corresponding article title into one cell.

How can I change my current code to use the last cell which is identified by "SO", as a reference point to combine all the authors as a string and return them into one cell.

```
Sub ReturnFAUResults()

    Dim r As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' reference results sheet
        If IsEmpty(.Range("A1")) Then .Range("A1").Value = "dummy header" ' if A1 is empty, put a "dummy" header to make AutoFilter work properly

        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Offset(, -1) ' reference referenced sheet column A range from row 1 down to column B last not empty cell
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=R[-1]C" ' fill referenced range blank cells with the same value as the not empty cell above
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=FAU"
            On Error Resume Next
            Set r = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Copy Worksheets("Search Results").Range("A7")
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).ClearContents ' clear cell with formulas
            If .Range("A1").Value = "dummy header" Then .Range("A1").ClearContents ' remove any "dummy" header
        End With
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you obtaining the data? It might be simpler to help you by starting there.

Comment: Your screenshots of data are virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Comment: Are you related to `faisal ahmed` who is also from Memphis and has asked a very similar question [How to concatenate multiple results using cell references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53956807/how-to-concatenate-multiple-results-using-cell-references)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, I posted with my brother's account because the earlier post didn't receive any attention. I have uploaded the link to the workbook at the very top. I am obtaining the data via a text file, but I recorded a macro to allow it to be split in to two columns.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look at this in depth.  But you can get your authors by article by looking at each article one-by-one, perhaps using the `PMID` row to detect the boundary between articles.  Or, you might be better off by using their API to access the database.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Is there a VBA function that I can use to set boundary limits between PMID and SO and then maybe concatenate results to one cell and loop?

Comment: You would have to write your own.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I would highly appreciate if you could point me in the right direction for the syntax to use

Comment: I would probably use the `Range.Find` method.